# Advice diagnosing Azure Reverse Proxy Gateway Timeouts

Tags: azure-web-app-service, reverse-proxy, arr

I've been using the ARR module in Azure App Service for a month or so (using the technique described [here](https://ruslany.net/2014/05/using-azure-web-site-as-a-reverse-proxy/), using it as a reverse proxy on *some* routes to forward requests to a Wordpress server.

The site on the AppService is an ASP.NET MVC site, with some paths using the proxy, the rest handled by MVC.

Everything was working great.

Then all of a sudden, i started receving intermittent 502 errors, only for the reverse proxy paths (all other routes that aren't proxyed and get handled by ASP.NET MVC are fine). In the IIS logs, the `sc-win32-status` is 12002. (['internet timed out'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/WinInet/wininet-errors). More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/troubleshooting-application-request-routing/troubleshooting-502-errors-in-arr#5023-timeout-errors))

Facts:

- The machine doesn't appear to be under stress (if it was, i'd expect all routes to be affected)
- Only the reverse proxy routes are timing out
- Downtime/slowness usually lasts 1-5 minutes
- I've tested the downstream server being proxy'ed to at the time of the issue, but it's always fine. Means it's the proxy, not the server.

The proxy rule looks like this:

```
 <rule name="Wordpress Blog - Hubs" stopProcessing="true"> 
     <match url="^(advice|lifestyle|news|wp-json|feed|about-us|contact-us|privacy-policy|terms-of-use)$" /> 
     <conditions> 
         <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.mysite.com.au" /> 
     </conditions> 
     <action type="Rewrite" url="https://mysite.wpengine.com/{R:1}" /> 
 </rule>
```

Here's what "Collect .NET Profiler Trace" captured:
[image]

Clicking on 'Details' doesn't help much:
[image]

The failed requests look like this:
[image]

So it's definetely the ARR module timing out, but i can't figure out how to tell why. Any ideas on how i can diagnose this? I'm not sure how to debug since it's not 'code', therefore things like ApplicationInsights won't help. I'm trying to take memory dumps but since it only ever occurs for < 5 mins, and memory dumps take longer than that to capture, it's hard to capture it in time.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: is all proxyed requests timed out? or you only get some response timeout?
I have experienced similar symptoms, in my case main cause was ARR proxy timeout too short (some requests execution time are longer than 30 seconds - default timeout value).

Comment: @Geunho it's all of them. It's like the ARR module locks up altogether. I could however try adding a proxy rule to _another_ site, just as a test - to see if it's isolated to just this particular downstream server, or the ARR module altogether.